# DropBox in MVC razor

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a DropBox that has 4 option .The options are taken from a list I make.
This is the list and the dropbox

```
 <div>
        @{
   List<SelectListItem> listItems= new List<SelectListItem>();
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
          Text = "SearchInputPosition",
          Value = "1"
        });
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "MissingNumber",
            Value = "2"

        });
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "ClimbStaircase",
            Value = "3"
        });

}
        </div>

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.textProblem, listItems, "-- Select Status --", new { id = "c", @onchange ="changeText(c)"})
```

If I select a value from the dropbox I want to display some text with a javascript function, but it displays undefined.

```
<script>
                var data = {        
            "1": "Given an array containing n distinct numbers taken from 0, 1, 2, ..., n, find the one that is missing from the array.",
            "2": "You are climbing a stair case. It takes n steps to reach to the top.Each time you can either climb 1 or 2 steps. In how many distinct ways can you climb to the top?",
            "3": "Write a function to delete a node (except the tail) in a singly linked list, given only access to that node.",
            }
            function changeText(id) {
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = data[id];
                }
    </script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a `change` event handler for `select` element and use its value.

```
<script>
        var data = {        
        "1": "Given an array containing n distinct numbers taken from 0, 1, 2, ..., n, find the one that is missing from the array.",
        "2": "You are climbing a stair case. It takes n steps to reach to the top.Each time you can either climb 1 or 2 steps. In how many distinct ways can you climb to the top?",
        "3": "Write a function to delete a node (except the tail) in a singly linked list, given only access to that node.",
        }
        var select=document.getElementById('textProblem');
        select.onchange=function(){
           document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = data[this.value];
        }
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't do a thing. At least not showing undefined :)

Comment: @GeorgeGreat, remove old change event

Comment: Removed from @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.textProblem, listItems, "-- Select Status --", new { id = "c", @onchange ="changeText(c)"})

Comment: Maybe you not have element with id=`textProblem`

Comment: I know the answer is really what I needed. ' Cannot set property 'onchange' of null' This is the error that I have.

Comment: It means that you don't have the select with this id.Try this: `var select=document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];`

Comment: Still having the error, I read somewhere that model => model.textProblem is the id and the name in the same time, can that be the problem?

Comment: No..it doesn't..must work with this : `var select=document.getElementById('textProblem');`